# Location of JFrame in middle of the window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, centering

My `JFrame` window always starts at the upper left corner. I want it to start in the middle of the screen. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple method:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setBounds` to declare the window's `x` and `y` position, along with it's `height` and `width`, if you know the `size` of the screen.

The other option is to use the `frame.setLocationRelativeTo()` method, and pass in `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);
```

Source: [How to set JFrame to appear centered, regardless of monitor resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442599/how-to-set-jframe-to-appear-centered-regardless-of-the-monitor-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void centreWindow(Window frame) {
   Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
   int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
   frame.setLocation(x, y);
}
```