# how can i align jframe into center of window in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

problem in alignment of JFrame in NetBeans. How can I set it in center of main window?

I have tried

```
public AdminLogin() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JFrame to appear centered, regardless of monitor resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442599/how-to-set-jframe-to-appear-centered-regardless-of-monitor-resolution)

Comment: Two lines of code does not give us the context of your code and how the method is used. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem when you ask a question so we don't have to guess what the code is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke the `setLocationRelativeTo( null )` after the size of the frame has been determined.

The basic structure for the code should be:

```
frame.add(...);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setVisible( true );
```