# How to center an Object in the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm not sure how i should center this. I tried to use locationRelativeTo null but the gameBoard stays in the top left corner.
But i need to center it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame game = new JFrame();
        game.setTitle("Game2048");
        game.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.setSize(420, 700);
        game.setResizable(false);
        game.add(new Game2048());
        // help here >>>>  game.setLocation();    
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to center an object in the JFrame or do you want to center the JFrame on the screen?

Comment: Only the object that i added.

Comment: Possible duplicate to ["How to set JFrame to appear centered, regardless of monitor resolution?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442599/how-to-set-jframe-to-appear-centered-regardless-of-monitor-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

See the javadoc of method [`setLocationRelativeTo(Component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo-java.awt.Component-):

> If the component is `null`, or the `GraphicsConfiguration` associated with this component is `null`, the window is placed in the center of the screen. The center point can be obtained with the `GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint` method.

That means, you can see simply use

```
game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

and your `JFrame game` will be placed in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can center two things here. First of all you can center the complete program window. This should be possible with

```
game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

The second thing to center is the component in the JFrame, in your case the Game2048 component. Therefore I can recommend the tutorial [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

When it comes to dimensions it isn't always simple to understand how they're used in Swing.

I would recommend you set your dimensions in the component Game2048 and let the JFrame apply the dimensions.

If you use a JPanel you could also use the setAlignment methods

```
panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
panel.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Only the object that i added.

Then the easiest way is to use a GridBagLayout for the content pane of the frame (instead of the default BorderLayout).

```
//game.add(new Game2048());
game.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
game.add(new Game2048, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Using the default constraints will cause the component to be centered in the space available.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information, especially the section on using the weightx/weighty constraints to understand why this works.